# Time Machine Restore Failure

Tags: time-machine, restore, time-capsule

I have been trying to do a restore for a week and it continues to fail. I will post pictures below but in a nutshell I had a 1 TB drive in my MBP that was almost full. While it was taking an update a few weeks ago it became corrupt. I used the Time Capsule sucessfully to restore the drive and used it for about two weeks before attempting this HDD upgrade to the two TB.

This time the restore will run overnight or 1 hour or any random amount of time before I get the error message. I thought perhaps that I had a heat issue so I’ve moved things around to keep both the MBP and the TC cool.

It almost finished last night after placing the old HDD in and doing a inspection of the backup on the TM. It was actually doing a “clean up to the restore” when I went to bed only to fail again.

I am trying this using the Ethernet port although the back ups were done via wireless. My MBP is a late 2011 model and the TC was purchased in 2012. I still have the complete 1 TB HDD that I can fall back on if need be. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I find it quite odd that Time Machine refuses to completely restore a backup onto your Mac. I do not know the reason for this, but try these methods (I honestly do not think it is a hardware problem):

- Restore from a older backup.
- Install MacOS completely, and try to backup with migration assistant.

These methods may take some time, but hopefully they work.